# DB21015E The Command Line Processor backend process request queue or input queue was not created within the timeout period

Tags: database, dns, db2, instance, redhat

Good day,

I just install db2 v10.5 into the redhat 7.5 server, the installation is done.
So for next step I am going to create an instance on it, by following command:

```
./db2icrt -a SERVER_ENCRYPT -s ese -u db2fenc -p db2c_inst db2inst1
```

I wait for around 15 minutes, and it fail. The log I saw from db2icrt.log is as follow:

```
DB21015E  The Command Line Processor backend process request queue or input 
queue was not created within the timeout period.
Update DBM cfg SYSADM_GROUP errcode = 8
DBI1281E  The database manager configuration file could not be
      initialized.
```

I try to google, some say that I need to configure `/etc/netsrv.conf`, but I think this is for AIX, may I know how can I fix this for redhat 7.5 OS?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details. (1) Did you have a *previous* Db2-version installed already on the RHEL hostname?  (may  be visible in the Db2 global registry use db2greg -dump to view). Sometimes environment variables like PATH have old directories.  (2) Did you try omitting the -p parameter ? (3) Did you run db2prereqcheck first?  (4) Are you trying with the fixpack-11 build?

Comment: What’s the result of the following commands? `ping $(hostname)`, `grep $(hostname) /etc/hosts`, `ifconfig -a`

Answer (score 0):

There a number of possible issues that can cause an error of this type, e.g.

- [invalid permissions on tmp](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2icrt-fails-dbi1281e-error-database-manager-configuration-file-could-not-be-initialized)
- [invalid permission in the install image in /opt](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/75-ways-demystify-db2-36-db2icrt-fails-error-dbi1281e-database-manager-configuration-file-could-not-be-initialized)

For debugging purposes, one can add `-d` flag to the `db2icrt`, tough this is mostly intended for Db2 support. If that wouldn't allow you to narrow down the problem, you need to raise a case to the vendor (IBM).